# Xubuntu 16.04 desktop icons after update

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, xfce, customization, desktop-icons

I did a clean install of Xubuntu 16.04 a couple of weeks back. I installed a few icon themes like Faba, Moka etc. However after recent software update, all the desktop icons have turned like this:

[image: Xubuntu 16.04 desktop icons misalignment]

I restarted my machine several times. I tried several commands like `clean` `autoclean` `autoremove` etc, but no result (it's all the same for default icons or any other third-party icons that I have installed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is because of a bug in `gtk2-engines-murrine` .

I rolled back to the previous version of the package:

`sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine=0.98.2-0ubuntu2`

and

Voila! Everything is properly aligned again!

[You can track the bug here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk2-engines-murrine/+bug/1598316)

Additionally if you don't want to upgrade this package automatically in future:

`sudo echo "gtk2-engines-murrine hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections`

Comment: On 17.04, I can't seem to find the package: `E: Version '0.98.2-0ubuntu2' for 'gtk2-engines-murrine' was not found`

Comment: Also, oddly they make it sound as if it is fixed in the version I have (`0.98.2-0ubuntu5`): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk2-engines-murrine/+bug/1598316/comments/20

Answer (score 0):

bytegenie's answer is correct and functions well. To do so in an automated way, run the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine=0.98.2-0ubuntu2 -y --allow-downgrades
sudo killall xfdesktop
```

This will automatically downgrade the package, and restart xfce's desktop service.